# What is the maximum power that I can get from a flyback controller?

Tags: power-supply, flyback

I'm trying to design my own power supply and I decided to use flyback topology.
But before chosing a controller for the circuit this question came up: how far can i get with the output power? since I will design the feedback winding for the current measurement why can't I just "fool" the controller by changing this parameter(feedback turns)?

Comment: Check out the Texas Instruments WebBench Designer.  It can design most of the supply for you in a few minutes.  http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page

Comment: thanks, but i need to understand the principles (more than the power supply itself actually...)

Comment: Most designers (including me :) ) prefer Flyback for up to 100-120W (less than 5A output current).

Comment: @RohatKılıç So.. Can i use TL3843 for a 60W (5A) power supply without any problems?

Comment: Of course you can, but PWM controller is not a limiting component; MOSFET, transformer and some other components are. By the way, I don't recommend Flyback topology for 5A output current. Because many problems show themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent limit to the power you can get from a flyback topology. It just happens to be more cost-effective for relatively low power applications. Many flyback converters control the peak current by a low-value external sense resistor in the switch source (or emitter) circuit.

I suggest auditing the Coursera courses on switchmode design (from the University of Colorado, I think). They're free to view (but unfortunately not the quizzes).

Answer (score 2):

The maximum energy storage depends on the Ohms per Henry loss 1/T=DCR/L, the saturation current maximum,Imax, the inductance, L and duty cycle of stored energy, *d*,  thus \$E_{max}=1/2 LI^2\$ but substitute realistic ratios for DCR/L and V/DCR one can derive  a limit for the product of these two or V/L which is = dI/dt and thus the Imax over the switching interval time dt can be used to derive Imax. The dt cancels out with the switching frequency as long as it reaches max current , Imax.

So what are cost-effective DCR/L ratios?
[e.g.](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/7449152111/7388694)

1. L= 117 nH, $2 (1k) DCR=1.43 mohm, 32 A \$E_{max}=60 ~mJ, T_{max}=\frac{L}{DCR}=0.82us , 12.2kΩ/H\$ thus to convert E to P \$Pmax=E/T=60~ mJ/0.82us=731W \$ but this would be at using a switch with much lower RdsOn or Rce and thus the Coss or Miller capacitance must limit the frequency to a much lower value and the rise time is reduced, resulting in a practical limit of around 200W.
   (proof TL:DW;)
   [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

I would say the you can calculate power capability by considering the peak current limit on the primary, and the duty cycle. For boundary mode, the duty cycle is known with the constraint the magnetizing inductance must have volt-second balance. I get D = Vout*Nps/(Vin+Vout*Nps), not considering the diode forward drop. Then the input current is .5*D*Ipk, on average. Multiply that by Vin and some efficiency derating, that's the answer I think.